# Can ugly groups have derived length 3?

Tags: gr.group-theory

Definitions: All groups referred to are finite solvable. Call such a group good if it can be constructed from the trivial group using central extensions and split extensions, call a group bad if it can not be so constructed. Call a group ugly if it is centerless and non-split. So, an ugly group is a finite solvable group with trivial center, and which does not have a nontrivial decomposition as a semi-direct product. Can an ugly group have derived length 3? Can an ugly group have 4-th power free order?

Comment: 1) A bad group must involve an ugly group, as a quotient of some subgroup.

2) By a result of Curran, a centerless group G of derived length 2 splits over G', so groups of derived length 2 can not be ugly, and must in fact be good. On ther other hand, D Holt used GAP to find ugly groups of derived length 4. Thus the question about derived length 3.

Comment: 3) Wreath products of cyclic groups are good, by definition, so by Kaloujnine-Krasner all (finite solvable) groups are subgroups of good groups. So goodness is not quotient-closed.

4) nilpotent, more generally supersolvable, more generally Sylow tower groups, are all good. Can the class be made larger without destroying subgroup-closed?

Comment: Do you have a reference for the construction of ugly groups by D Holt? (Was it Hardy who said that there was no place in this world for ugly mathematics?) –

Comment: You have a definition of ugly groups, and two questions about ugly groups. Before this there is a definition of bad/good groups, with no question about them. Why did you introduce the definition of good/bad groups with no question about them?

Comment: The definitions of good and bad groups are motivation for the definition of an ugly group. Ugly groups are obstacles to goodness.

Comment: On Thu, Apr 19, 2012 at 10:53 AM, Derek Holt <D.F.Holt@warwick.ac.uk> wrote:
> I did a check through the small groups database (in GAP and Magma) and found that two groups of order 768:
> SmallGroup(768, 1085345)  and
> SmallGroup(768, 1085350)
> have this property. They are the only examples of order up to 1000. Bothe of these examples have derived length 4.  I think it would be difficult to find a metabelian example, but they might still exist!
> Best regards,
> Derek Holt.

Comment: There are no further examples of order up to $2000$ except possibly for order $1536$. There are $408641062$ groups of order $1536$, so that will take longer to check! I would guess that there no examples of derived length $3$, but I could be wrong.